# How to login to different tenant(non default) in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Please help me.

I have lost my phone having Authenticator app which helps me in logging in  to default tenant. This tenant is not important for me. Can any one help me sharing any way in logging into other tenants in azure portal with out logging into default tenant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add the tenant name to `https://portal.azure.com/`, you will log into the tenant you specified.

`https://portal.azure.com/{your tenant}`

Answer (score 1):

The URL you propose seems to not work anymore.
As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/727465/locked-out-of-my-default-directory-because-tenant), you need to use the following URL:

```
https://portal.azure.com/{your tenant}.onmicrosoft.com
```

For example, if the tenant name you want to access is `bigcompany` (perhaps you work at `bigcompany.com`), you can log into that using:

```
https://portal.azure.com/bigcompany.onmicrosoft.com
```